# How i install gmail_smtp.git script plugin?

Tags: php, heroku

I have heroku PHP app.I want to send emails through my app.For this implementation, i want to use gmail smtp server which is supported by heroku.
**https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/11/9/tech_sending_email_with_gmail**
The above following article is saying that, install plugin like this
**script/plugin install git://github.com/adamwiggins/gmail_smtp.git**.
While i am doing this, i am getting an error like
**bash: script/plugin: No such file or directory**.
Can any one help me in describing the steps to install gmail_smtp for my heroku app.
is there any free email APIs which are supported by heroku to send mail through my heroku app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Rails plugin.  It will not run inside of a PHP application.

You should find something that does this for PHP.